# Google API HTTP 401 - Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-sites

I'm struggling with google api for a few days while sending a post request to Google sites API via  C# application.

First I redeem the authorization code from google's servers by a GET request:

```
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
    scope=email%20profile&
state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oa2cb.mydomain/myHome&
    redirect_uri=http://localhost&
    response_type=code&
    client_id= // CLIENT ID here...
    access_type=online&
    approval_prompt=auto
```

In the redirect uri I got the authorization code which I use to claim the
access token:

```
string RequestUrl;

            RequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(RequestUrl);
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "code=4/aPJAhLvlGLxw1fjKDCOpEQjfoVtNDZYq7FzvrziUero#&" +
                "client_id=//cilent id here&" +
                "client_secret=client secret here&" +
                "redirect_uri=http://localhost&" +
                "grant_type=authorization_code";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

The response containing the token looks like that:

```
{
 "access_token": "ya29.pAGX8f4e0ZyBazzq5rxWVS6lL1jRyj0_GCog5UEO3FiGT2h4cj10jee4ziAoA09vHRoVejN5p7Iw",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE2NWQ2MzcwZTgzOTI5YmE4Y2E4ZWU5OTMzZTExZjg2Yzg4YzAwNjUifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTA1OTc0NjQwMTUzNzU0NjU1MDE5IiwiYXpwIjoiOTkwMzUxMjA1MzY4LXBudGYxZXNtaXQ3a3Zlbmg5cnRvbW5pMmdhMmY0N2ZsLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJuaXIuazFAaGFpZmFuZXQub3JnLmlsIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6Imc5MU5wOVRYS2JUaVEzcFpTM2Ewa1EiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXVkIjoiOTkwMzUxMjA1MzY4LXBudGYxZXNtaXQ3a3Zlbmg5cnRvbW5pMmdhMmY0N2ZsLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiaGQiOiJoYWlmYW5ldC5vcmcuaWwiLCJpYXQiOjE0MzU4MjI2ODAsImV4cCI6MTQzNTgyNjI4MH0.CeaQ8S3GG-yeAwqjU1ixdB7ro2SVKp2QdVTXNWl6196oJeQU1LFLpZ9FtrpNEGSDKHXrO5zx0ldE52RYw8TwMKILUqqCHLOewVJQMjZ6tiPzt-b-qeUta6Op4Z9HerwkMK2sofl88G-XZ6jKc7gk1gGPVcATBU7x0-QPRhQxmDUzP7zceVeoOtBD8g7liVHakK9sA5RNonGt-N6SvzECqhSLss7kDuXc4dStnENhyv_9oTIpvVsQplE-cJz7fDHC7mkW7BfwsgKBE8XbruBz5-o3AG5RVGyUTYqDaoq9qr3_NqckiRISUS127scaYwcYPE22Q8L_2AnpfJU0vuxo6g"
}
```

And the final step is to call the google api using the `access_token`
this way:

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/mydomain");
        req.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
        req.Host = "sites.google.com";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Headers["Gdata-version"] = "1.4";
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ya29.pAGX8f4e0ZyBazzq5rxWVS6lL1jRyj0_GCog5UEO3FiGT2h4cj10jee4ziAoA09vHRoVejN5p7Iw";

        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:sites='http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008'><title>Source Site</title><summary>A new site to hold memories</summary><sites:theme>slate</sites:theme></entry>");
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
            {

                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string i = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```

But at the end of this step I get a 401 http error.

```
Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: any reason you don't want to use Googles client library and want to do it the hard way?

Comment: I need that this operation will be automatic. The application connects to database pulls data, gets the api token and uses the google api accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are authenticating your users using the following scopes

> scope=email%20profile&

The Sites Data API uses the following scope: `https://sites.google.com/feeds/`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you be more specific?

Comment: So the scope should be the same in both requests?

Comment: Scopes tell the authentication server and the user what permissions you need what things you intend to access. by sending email and profile you just told them that you wanted to access there email and information about there Google profile.  You didn't ask for access to there site data.  Glad it works now