# 401 Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, google-contacts-api

I have app in react and from there I am authenticating google user 
and returning `access_token`, and I am passing that access token to rails API.

Now on rails side I am using below code from get google contacts.

```
 contacts_josn = JSON.parse(open("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token="+params[:access_token]+"&alt=json").read)
```

But its returning me error

```
#<OpenURI::HTTPError: 401 Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope>
```

Update:
Suggested answer is different from my question, I am using google contacts API.

Any suggestion will be appreciate :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google API HTTP 401 - Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178512/google-api-http-401-token-invalid-authsub-token-has-wrong-scope)

Comment: No its not duplicate, please check my question first.

Comment: Ok then please check [mcve]. Did you even tried the solution?

Comment: I already tried many solutions, and I know how to ask question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue, this is issue of scope in access_token

When I am generating access_token from react, I was not give any scope. and from backend side I am using that access_token to fetch contacts

So what I did is

In react

```
<GoogleLogin
        className="pull-right btn btn-orange add-new-btn"
        clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
        scope="email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"
        buttonText="Import google contacts"
        onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
        onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
      >
```

Added scope `email` for email access and `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/` for manage contacts.

On Rails side

```
contacts_josn = JSON.parse(open("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=50&alt=json", "Authorization" =>  "Bearer #{params[:access_token]}", "GData-Version" => "3.0").read)
```

Now this will return contacts list.